# Why such slow download of windows support software?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I have been trying to download the Windows support drivers for Boot Camp all day, using a wired gigabit network connection.

The indicator gets about half way along then refuses to move. There is plenty of space on the USB hard drive I'm sending the drivers to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the Boot Camp Support Software directly from [here](http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1638/en_US/BootCamp5.0.5033.zip) (554 MB).

A workaround with instructions and link to download can be found [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1638):

1. The download file is a `.zip` file. Double click it to uncompress it,  if it is not automatically uncompressed.
2. Double-click the `Boot Camp5` folder.
3. Copy the entire contents of the `.zip` file to the root level of a USB flash drive or hard drive that is formatted with the FAT file system.
4. When running Windows, locate the `Boot Camp` folder on the USB media you created in Step 3 and double click to open it.
5. Double click on `setup` to start installing the Boot Camp Support Software.
6. When prompted to allow changes, click on `Yes` and follow the onscreen instructions.
7. Installation can take a few minutes. Don't interrupt the installation process. When installation is complete, click `Finish` in the dialog that appears.
8. A system restart dialog box appears.  Click `Yes` to complete the installation.

For detailed information about Boot Camp, please visit [this link](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5628).

Comment: Where is the downloading stored? I stop the downloading process, and I want to delete the files in my computer.

Comment: Ok, we can download that zip. But how BC 5.1.4 will locate it? There is no possibility NOT to download that support software from internet :-(

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of macOS Boot Camp Assistant, e.g. Monterey here, the Windows driver download is an un-skipable step in the setup.

My download meter says it's capped at 1 MB/s.

So there's that, blame it on Apple, who probably wants us to feel miserable for putting Windows on a perfectly fine Mac.